# Qual melhor forma de resolver lentidão para gerar relatório?

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho

A um tempo, desenvolvi uma página de relatórios, os usuário tem uma opção de filtros, esta funcionando, mas conforme os dados na base de dados estão crescendo esta ficando mais lento e não sei qual melhor opção para resolver esse problema, algumas das coisas que pensei foram:

- Se sempre é melhor trazer os dados já calculados pela query ou se em alguns casos, é melhor retornar todos os dados, e fazer esses calculas com uso do php, por exemplo?
- Será que estou criando corretamente as querys?
  O que quero dizer com isso, estou fazendo as contas em várias sub-querys, segue um exemplo:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT t.nome_tag,
      (
          SELECT count(vw.tag_id) FROM view_relatorio vw
          WHERE vw.tag_id = t.id AND vw.cliente_id IN (1,2,3,10,20)
            AND vw.conforme = 1 AND vw.dt_validate >= '2016-09-09'
      ) as conforme,

      (
          SELECT count(vw.tag_id) FROM view_relatorio vw
          WHERE vw.tag_id = t.id AND vw.cliente_id IN (1,2,3,10,20)
            AND vw.conforme = 0
      ) as naoConforme,

      (
          SELECT count(vw.tag_id) FROM view_relatorio vw
          WHERE vw.tag_id = t.id AND vw.cliente_id IN (1,2,3,10,20)
      ) as totalAtribuido

  FROM view_relatorio view
  JOIN tag t ON t.id = view.tag_id
  WHERE view.cliente_id IN (1,2,3,10,20)
  ```

Lembrando que esse é um pequeno exemplo e tem várias outras querys.

Já construí views para melhorar, conforme li em alguns lugares, também já indexei colunas nas tabelas necessárias, enfim, quanto a melhorar a parte do banco de dados já fiz diversos ajustes.

Comment: cara faz uma rotina para gerar o resultado por dia e guarda em uma view no mysql dai vc so le esta view , o processamento vai ficar bem melhor

Comment: essa era uma opção que também pensei, já usei isso em outro sistema, mas nesse caso, querem os dados em tempo real, mas muito obrigado pela ideia.

Comment: Uma sugestão, o primeiro passo é medir o qto tempo demora a query, o segundo eu faria uma experiência trocaria essas subconsultas por 3 consultas e no final faria o union delas agora se melhora a performace só medindo. Não esqueça dos comandos [analyze](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) e [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) eles podem ajudar a identificar gargalos nas consultas.

Comment: eu posso estar enganado, mas parece que você esta tentando obter os dados de maneiras repetidas para cada item do loop interno, quando poderia resolver isto no `JOIN` e no PHP agruparia os dados.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer esse teste que o @rray comentou, mas pelo que estou observando em outras querys que tenho, me parece que não irá melhorar muito, mas não custa testar.

Comment: Também preciso testar o que o @GuilhermeNascimento comentou, pois pode ser uma solução, apesar de um pouco mais trabalhosa agora, mas é uma opção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 3 queries estão praticamente repetidas (uma para pegar os conformes, uma pega os não-conformes e uma pega o total).
Count() é uma operação que por padrão custa para o banco porque tem que varrer os registros. Além disso tem JOINs em 4 queries.
O banco não consegue aproveitar essas repetições todas. Nesse caso é melhor fazer uma query que pega um tabelão e ir somando em um array mesmo.
Outra sugestão é rever o modelo dos dados para ver o que pode ser melhorado (separar em mais tabelas: por exemplo [tag_id, cliente_id, conforme] ou até mesmo só [tag_id, conforme]).
Para medir o tempo, dê uma olhada no comando "EXPLAIN ...". Ele apresenta como será executada a query.

Comment: Essa me parece até com o que o @GuilhermeNascimento comentou, vou ter que fazer uns testes e trabalhar em cima, não será simples, mas espero que seja uma alternativa e que melhore a performance. Obrigado